# Calculate the position of an orbiting object

Tags: javascript, animation, trigonometry

I'm creating a solar system animation using canvas and have a problem calculating an object's position (x,y) values.

Earth is orbiting around the Sun, and I need to calculate and update the Earth's position at each frame. And using Earth's position, I'll orbit the Moon around the Earth.

The related function is this:

```
orbitAround : function (master) {
    master.makeOrbitCenter();
    this.increaseOrbitAngle();
    context.rotate(this.orbit.angle * Math.PI/180);
    context.translate(this.orbit.distance, 0);

    // calculate and update the X and Y position of the earth
    // so that luna can orbit around earth
    // these are the initial values of earth
    this.position.x = master.position.x + this.orbit.distance;
    this.position.y = master.position.y;
},
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/ra3oLcq4/)

To make it simpler, I've drawn this picture

[image]

Let's say the blue disc is the Earth, and is located at (300,200). The Sun is at (200,200) and the distance between them is 100. After the Earth makes a 45 degree rotation around the Sun, what would its position be? How can I calculate it using the given values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you've got something working there, but here's a breakdown:

`Math.cos` and `Math.sin` return a theoretical `x` and `y` position along an axis. They need to be given the angle in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).

So, in order to get the position of a 45 degree angle, you essentially need to calculate the radian equivalent of degrees first.

```
var degrees = 45;
var radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
```

The result here is 0.785398163. You can then get the `x` and `y` coordinate of the orbiting object using this:

```
var x = Math.cos(0.785398163) * distance;
var y = Math.sin(0.785398163) * distance;
```

The whole process for a single frame would look like this:

```
var distance = 100; // from the centre of orbit
var degrees = 45; // around a 360 degree orbit
var radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

var x = Math.cos(radians) * distance;
var y = Math.sin(radians) * distance;
```

Here's a very basic [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4j9a2rwj/) with square planets and everything.

Comment: After Leo's answer, I started to experiment and got it kind of working, but since you shined some light on the subject, I'll accept yours. Now it's fully working. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/ra3oLcq4/1/).

Comment: @akinuri glad the extra explanation helped.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
distance = 100; //distance between earth and sun.

getXPosition = function(angle){
    return distance*(Math.cos(Math.PI * (angle/180))); 
};

getYPosition = function(angle){
    return distance*(Math.sin(Math.PI * (angle/180))); 
};

var x = getXPosition(45); //70.71 from the sun
var y = getYPosition(45); //70.71 from the sun
```

And to get the final position just do this:

```
x += 200; //200 = sun position
y -= 200; //200 = sun position
```