# Calculating cordanates with angles

Tags: javascript, math, angle

So basically I have the starting vectors and the angels but the code I'm working with only updates my angle and I'm trying to get to another vector.

```
var start_x = 0;
var start_y = 0;
var speed = 200;
var current_x; //This needs to be calculated 
var current_y; //This needs to be calculated 
var current_angle = 53;
```

How could I calculate the current X vector and Y vector using the speed and the starting positions? I've browsed around this site and others but I cant seem to find an answer.

Comment: This isn't really a programming problem, it's a maths problem. Once you figure out the appropriate formulae the JavaScript part will be easy. Have you tried http://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Even though the answers below give you the mathematical approach to solve this, it's implementation might differ. Can you be more specific about your project? Are you making a canvas animation? Where exactly do you want to calculate x and y in your code? What'll you be doing with it?

Comment: despite the good answers already given, you might want to read up on [trigonometry](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trigonometry.html). It's more fun if you understand why it works.

Comment: Yes, Im trying to make a canvas animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay there you [image: your question in graph representation]

Firstly you have speed, so you need to take a time frame too so let us assume we need the co-ordinates after 1s. The formula to measure Speed is V = S/T
where V is velocity(speed in a direction) S is distance and T is time.
Therefore S = VxT
According to your speed 200, Distance travelled in 1 second is 200M
now we have the angle too which you gave it as 53deg.
Hence we can draw an imaginary triangle to find (x,y) the new co-ordinates which are unknown.
To know x,y the formula is

```
y= sin(theta) x Distance
x = cos(theta) x Distance
```

where theta is equal to 53deg and distance is 200
hence (x,y) = ()

To be a bit more descriptive, in our imaginary triangle y is opposite and x is adjacent, and x,y are nothing but distances from 0,0 . There is a formula in trigonometry, which states that

```
Sin(theta) = opposite/Hypotenuse
 hence 53 = unknown/200
similarly
Cos(theta) = Adjacent/Hypotenuse
 hence 53 = unknown/200
 So after calculating we get the result (120.36,159.72)
```

So in java script you can use

```
// since Math.cos takes input in radians you  have to convert it into degrees.

    var speed = 200;
    var time = 1;
    var angle = 53;
    x = (Math.cos(angle*(Math.PI/100))* (speed*time);
    y = (Math.sin(angle*(Math.PI/100))* (speed*time);
```

**We have calculated using radians not degrees, so you might need necessary conversion into  degrees but thats not difficult just interchange (x,y) to (y,x) which would be the result with degrees.**

Answer (score 2):

Vector math is hard so I would write a little class to do all the heavy lifting:

```js
function LameVector(x,y) {
  this.startx = this.x = x;
  this.starty = this.y = y;
  this.angle = false;
  this.mag = 0;
  
  this.moveXY = function (x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    this.angle = Math.atan2(this.y - this.starty, this.x - this.startx) * 180 / Math.PI;
    this.mag = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.y - this.starty, 2) + Math.pow(this.x - this.startx, 2));
  }
  
  this.move = function (speed, angle) {
    var ang = angle / 180 * Math.PI;
    this.moveXY(speed * Math.cos(ang), speed * Math.sin(ang));
  }
}
var o = document.getElementById("out");
var vec1 = new LameVector(0, 0); // starting position 0,0
o.innerHTML += "start x " + vec1.x + ", start y " + vec1.y + "<br>";

vec1.move(200, 53); // move 200 units at angle 53 deg
o.innerHTML += "move1 x " + vec1.x + ", move1 y " + vec1.y + "<br>";

vec1.move(200, 27); // move 200 more units at angle 27 deg
o.innerHTML += "move2 x " + vec1.x + ", move2 y " + vec1.y + "<br>";

// can also get the angle and length
o.innerHTML += "final angle " + vec1.angle + ", magnitude " + vec1.mag + "<br>";
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've came across this problem before ([Calculate the position of an orbiting object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526438/calculate-the-position-of-an-orbiting-object)) and used the following.

You'll be using `Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` methods and they take angles in radians as a parameter. So

```
var start_x = 0;
var start_y = 0;
var speed = 200;
var current_x; //This needs to be calculated 
var current_y; //This needs to be calculated 
var current_angle = 53;

// converting degrees to radian
var angleInRad = current_angle * (Math.PI / 180);

var time = 1; // second
var distance = speed * time;

// calculate the x and y values
current_x = Math.cos(angleInRad) * distance;
current_y = Math.sin(angleInRad) * distance;

console.log(current_x, current_y); // 120.36, 159.72
```

Comment: I dont think you can pass speed as a parameter unless you are getting the co-ordinates in a second.

Comment: to be more specific you need to pass distance not speed which is speed*time, since speed = distance/time

Comment: your reference also takes distance as parameter please check

Comment: Fixed. If he's making a canvas animation, and getting the object's position at each frame, this `time` variable is irrelevant, and his `speed` variable equals to the distance. He just needs to name it better.